# How to create valid keycloak token in Java?

Tags: java, token, jwt

I have secret, client id and user data. How to create valid keycloak token with full payload using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) [repo](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt) or any other in Java:

> jti, exp, sub, aud, nbf, itp...
>
> "allowed-origins": [
>       "http://localhost:8080",
>       "http://localhost:4200"   ], itp...
>
> "realm_access": {
>       "roles": [
>         "uma_authorization"
>       ]
>     }, itp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old but maybe it helps someone. You can use the keycloak admin library to get a token from your keycloak.

Code:

```
Keycloak instance = Keycloak.getInstance(keycloakUrl, keycloakRealm, keycloakUsername, keycloakPassword, keycloakClientId, keycloakClientSecret);
TokenManager tokenmanager = instance.tokenManager();
String keycloakToken = tokenmanager.getAccessTokenString();
```

POM import:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>20.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively you can request a token from the token endpoint from your keycloak.